# Postgres Regex Replace

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, select

I have a table like this:

```
Column
-------------
CURSE IS BAD
DON'T CURSE
IWILLCURSE
```

I want output like this:

```
Column
-------
*** IS BAD
DON'T ***
IWILLCURSE
```

I want to replace only if it matches on full word.

I tried the following: `REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '( |CURSE)', '***', 'g')` but it gives output like this:

```
Column
-------
******IS BAD
DON'T ***
IWILLCURSE
```

There are multiple curse words which I want to handle in this. Another option is the `CASE` statement but there are more than 50 curse words which I want to replace.

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '\yCURSE\y', '***', 'g')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundary `\y`:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '\yCURSE\y', '***', 'g')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a845a3e51cefb49621fa39b231bd0b22)**:

```
select col, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '\yCURSE\y', '***', 'g') new_col
from (values ('CURSE IS BAD'), ('DON''T CURSE'), ('IWILLCURSE')) t(col)
```

```
col          | new_col   
:----------- | :---------
CURSE IS BAD | *** IS BAD
DON'T CURSE  | DON'T *** 
IWILLCURSE   | IWILLCURSE
```